# how to pass a function name via JSON and call it in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, triggers

I have a JSON string which includes a function I need to call.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{  
    "type":"listview",
    // the function I would like to call
    "content":"dynoData.getRetailers()",
    "custom_classes":["","nMT pickList","",""],
    "lib":"static_listview.html",
    "tmp":"tmp_listview_inset",
    "lang":"locale_search",
    ...
```

I'm using this to assemble a jQuery Mobile listview on the client. To get the dynamic data, I need to call `dynoData.getRetailers()`.

However I'm struggling to make the call :-)

This is what I'm trying:

```
var dyn = $.parseJSON( passed_JSON_string ),
    content = dyn.content;
```

I had hoped calling it would trigger the function but it just returns the function name as a string.

**Question**:
How can trigger the actual function?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
I'm putting the JSON string on the HTML element on the actual page, which I will replace with the element I'm building. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul data-template="true" data-config='{  
    "type":"listview",
    "content":"dynoData.getRetailers()",
    "custom_classes":["","nMT pickList","",""],
    "lib":"static_listview.html",
    "tmp":"tmp_listview_inset",
    "lang":"locale_search",
    "theme":"c",
    "filter":"true"
    }'></ul>
```

I could put all of these into `data-` attributes, but that would be messy...

**Solution**:
This worked:

1) change JSON to:

```
..."method":"getRetailers", ...
```

2) call from Javascript:

```
content = dynoData[ dyn.method ]();
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you tried using `eval()`

Comment: No, because I'm told `eval is evil`. I never use. Is there another way?

Comment: can you change the json, to avoid using `eval()` ?

Comment: hm. change to what? Wait I post my HTML, which contains the JSON string.

Comment: Is the function that you need to call dynamic or will it always be that same function? I like your eval is evil, lol, I must remember that :)

Comment: the function is always the same.

Comment: You could just check for a specific value instead of the function name, and then call the function (hard coded)

Comment: @eskimo: I'm trying that just now.

Comment: So you want to run some JavaScript code you pass, but you don't want to have it eval'd. There's a problem. All JS that runs is effectively eval'd. If it wasn't, it wouldn't run. If you're going to execute some code, that means you're going to execute some code. It'll be up to you to ensure that it isn't malicious.

Comment: @IHateLazy: I'm trying to live by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). Since I'm targeting slow mobile devices, I'm not touching eval (otherwise I would have used the JQM widget out-of-the-box long time ago :-)

Comment: Yes, but ultimately you're going to execute some code from input that can't be known by the "compiler". Somehow I doubt that reading object properties will make much difference. Can't say for certain without testing I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the function is always part of the `dyn` object you can use notation like following to call a function:

```
dyn['dynoData']['getRetailers']();
```

So if you are able to adjust json you could send back something like:

```
"content":{ "mainObject": "dynoData" , "method" :"getRetailers"}
```

And translate it to your dynamic function using variables:

```
  dyn[content.mainObject][content.method]();
```

As an example using jQuery try using the following :

```
$('div')['hide']();
```

Which is the same as :

```
$('div').hide()
```

Comment: ah. That looks nice, too. Will try. Thanks

Comment: thanks, but this way is only for call method in an object. It has to force write callback method in below way: 

    var callbacks = function() {
        var method = function() {};

        return {method1 : method};
    }();

Answer (score 1):

As charlietfl pointed out you can use object notation to call functions. For your case you have to get rid off `()` and split it, then call it like this;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var temp = $('ul').data('config').content.replace(/\(\)/g, '').split('.');
    window[temp[0]][temp[1]]();
});
```

However this could solve your problem, if you think about future, you have to extend it a little bit. This way even you don't know the depth, you can call it anyway;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var temp = $('ul').data('config').content.replace(/\(\)/g, '').split('.'), func, i, il = temp.length;
    for(i = 0; i < il; i++) {
        if(func == null) {
            func = window[temp[i]];
            continue;
        }
        func = func[temp[i]];
    }
    func();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ConversationJS.  It makes dynamic calls pretty easy and its a great way to decouple your codebase: https://github.com/rhyneandrew/Conversation.JS

Comment: ah. I will have to take a look. Spaghetti script it is... :-)

Comment: Conversation will actually help you prevent spaghetti because none of the functions are explicitly called.  Instead, they are "spoken to" by sending a string that they are "listening for".  It's pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

JSON is purely data notation to be passed around so it is easily read and parsed, therefore it has no concept of functions. However, there are other ways of dealing with this and if you are starting to think that that is the only way to deal with your dilemma, then take a step back and examine your design. Instead of using this:

```
eval(yourCode);
```

Try this

```
var tempFun = new Function(yourCode);
tempFun();
```

Comment: sorry. I'm not `evaling`. See my comments above.

Comment: avoiding `eval` on json however is good practice to avoid script injection

Comment: My bad I pressed enter by accident and then just decided to edit it, please feel free to relook over my answer now