# Remove Double Quotes in Json String - for Function calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

Am working on JQGrid where I am loading the ColName & ColModel Dynamically using this Example [jqGrid and dynamic column binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding)

Everything looks good. Am using Formatter in one of the Columns for Formatter

```
function UrlFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
}
```

When I write Columns in .JS it looked like this

```
colmodel :[{ name: 'somenam', formatter: UrlFmatter, width: 95, align: "center", index: 'somenam'}]
```

As am loading Dynamically now it is not working as the function is not called i suppose.

I thought `formatter: "UrlFmatter"` it is loaded like this and making it a string. How do i make this function call ?

Or is there some better way I can handle these scenarios ?

Comment: `formatter: UrlFmatter` is the right way. Where are you defining the `function UrlFmatter()`

Comment: yes that is the right way.But wen coming in json "" appended. if i remove that it ll call that function or anyother way

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792329/how-to-pass-a-function-name-via-json-and-call-it-in-javascript-jquery) for getting to know how to call function name that occurs in json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems exact duplicate of your old question. As I answered before (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412370/315935)) you should replace definition of `UrlFmatter` from

```
function UrlFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<a href='DetailResult?airportname=" + options.rowId + "' >" +
        cellvalue + "</a>";
}
```

to

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        urlFmatter: function (cellValue, options) {
            return "<a href='DetailResult?airportname=" + options.rowId + "' >" +
                cellvalue + "</a>";
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

You should include the above code *directly after* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or after `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). After that you can modify

```
{ name: 'somenam', formatter: UrlFmatter, width: 95, align: "center", index: 'somenam'}
```

to

```
{ name: 'somenam', formatter: "urlFmatter", width: 95, align: "center"}
```

Comment: Agree itz a duplicate. i marked tat as a solution :) Thanks for ur help